# Sphinx describe valid input values to api

Tags: python, api, flask, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I've been using sphinx to document our api. As one might expect, there are certain parameters in our api for whose values are a restricted set. For example, there might be an "on" parameter for a post which describes a tv, and the same parameter might be available for filtering on a GET.

My problem has been that I can't find a built-in way to describe valid parameter values. For bools I'm ok with just putting it in parens, but some parameters have 20 valid input values, and some have multiple possible sets of input params depending on the value of multiple variable points in the route. For example:

```
myapi.com/<string:gameConsoleId>/games/<string:gameId>
```

Internally, we don't allow any possible value for `gameConsoleId` or `gameId`. We want a `gameConsoleId` to be a `PLAYSTATION`, or an `XBOX`, or a `NINTENDO`. The same is true of the `gameId`. If you pass a mario game to a playstation console, it should return an error, and we want to document that.

Is this a sign that the api needs to be designed differently, or am I just missing how to do the documentation norms?

---

To be more clear, I am trying to figure out how to do something in Sphinx. Specifically, I am looking for correct syntax, commands, or norms for documenting the valid input parameters to an api endpoint. It is clear to me how to document that there is a valid input parameter.

Query string parameter:

```
:query gameConsoleId: The type of game console
```

Json Parameter (for POST etc):

```
:<json string gameConsoleId: The type of game console
```

What isn't clear to me is how to document the valid values for those inputs. We have valid inputs defined, it just isn't clear to me how to communicate that through Sphinx.

For example, below are the valid inputs to gameConsoleId:

```
[PLAYSTATION,XBOX,NINTENDO]
```

Comment: Might be a better question for [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) if you're asking about documentation and design.

Comment: If this is primarily about sphinx, then it would be more of an implementation issue and on-topic here at SO.  If it's primarily about documentation and design then it would probably fit on Progs as @Celeo calls out.

Comment: `I can't find a built-in way to describe valid parameter values` -- Seems like run-of-the-mill validation to me.  Or are you asking about something else, like a REST URL that is self-documenting with respect to its valid values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach is to look at existing documentation of a popular and well-documented project such as Python itself. Python documentation uses several methods to documenting parameters that can take one of a set of values:

1. Textual form as in [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile):

> The mode parameter should be 'r' to read an existing file, 'w' to truncate and write a new file, or 'a' to append to an existing file.

2. Bullet list of values, possibly with descriptions, as in [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod):

> mode may take one of the following values (as defined in the stat module) or bitwise ORed combinations of them:

- stat.S_ISUID
- stat.S_ISGID
- stat.S_ENFMT

3. Table of values and their descriptions as in [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

### Edit

In the spirit of this answer, the documentation for the [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) `order` parameter starts as follows:

> order : {'K', 'A', 'C', 'F'}, optional

Here we see that the allowed values are written as the type. That is, rather than specifying that `order` takes the type `str` and then explaining what specific `str` values are allowed, the set of values that are allowed are listed as the type and users infer the type is `str`.

Comment: I'm going to just add that this cheat-sheet is a super helpful compliment to this:  http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/cheatsheet.html